# Change the elements' delimiter in a list in python

Tags: python, list

If I have a list:
`list=['ABC CBC', 'abc cbcc', 'Aabc Abbc']`
How can I change it into below:
`list=['ABC_CBC', 'abc_cbcc', 'Aabc_Abbc']`

Comment: `list = [item.replace(' ','_') for item in list]`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd strongly recommend you not to use keywords like list,str,int for variables.

Coming to your solution, This should work:

```
list1=['ABC CBC', 'abc cbcc', 'Aabc Abbc']
list1=[i.replace(' ','_') for i in list1]
>>['ABC_CBC', 'abc_cbcc', 'Aabc_Abbc']
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks buddies!